# how to send a http request in the background in javascript？

Tags: javascript

I have a button, the event would be onclick and then the javascript function will send to server the request(for example a rating button on an item), the page should not be redirected, basically I want the event to happen in the background. How to do that? Please give me some idea or code.

Comment: The keyword is AJAX. Please google for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the marvelous world of AJAX. One of the issues with ajax calls is that different browsers have different implementations of ajax. It's better if you can use a javascript library that abstracts these differences. I'd suggest you to pick up jQuery. You can make ajax calls in jQuery using `$.get()`, `$.post()` or `$.ajax()`

Comment: +1 for giving a little more info. See @grc's answer for a link to the [jQuery project](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery ajax to achieve your goal. Its quite simple :)